# How to find Quality images PHP

Tags: php, algorithm

I was trying to find how i can find the best quality images(which having good Colors + Brightness ) from the set of images which is provided by the users.

I am using JPGE

Right now i am just finding high Resolution pics , but some times it display bad photos which having Hi-Res.

Comment: What is your definition of "high quality"?

Comment: which type of image your using jpg/png/gif.if original image color or quality is not good then we unable to create any effect on it.it's totally depend upon original picture quality.

Comment: Good colors & brightness is very relative

Comment: no doubt quality of gif and png is 50 times better than jpg.when we change png/gif to jpeg it's loose it's colors.i face this problem few days back but if your original picture quality is good then i will try to help you.

Answer (score 1):

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13436038/gd-imagick-code-to-find-if-an-image-is-well-focussed-or-not/13436065#13436065), and the answer, might be related to your request. Effectively, if you're planning on implementing the filters yourself, you'll need to ask yourself exactly what you consider a "good" image.

The poster from yesterday had a very decent idea of what he had in mind. He wanted to kill blurred images, and this is easily done using an edge detector. In your case, brightness is also pretty easy to do - calculate the variation of brightness across an image, and compare it to a pre-defined value.

Comment: Hello , I am asking the same question , please can you provide me PHP example. It will be great help